# How can I use another table for authentication in Laravel 7

Tags: authentication, laravel-7

Im very new with Laravel and had already seen many tutorials, so now  I know little more. But I am struggling with a problem that I can't solve. I want to use another table(t_clients) that already exists in my DB instead of users table made by migration for authentication. I already read the documentation on website , so I changed in auth.php this:

```
    'providers' => [
//        'users' => [
//            'driver' => 'eloquent',
//            'model' => App\User::class,
//        ],
         'users' => [
             'driver' => 'database',
             'table' => 't_clients',
         ],
    ],
```

Now  when I try to login I get the next error : `ErrorException Undefined index: id`. So I tried the next one and this problem is temporary fixed, I changed the primary_key name in the table "t_clients" to "id" and login works. The original column name is "pk_client". But I want actually that the primary_key remains unchanged. I want actually that by authentication, Laravel search for "pk_client" and not "id". Does anyone know how I can fix this? I appreciate your help.

Spec project:
Laravel Framework 7.1.0
mysql  Ver 8.0.18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was fixed by making a Client EloquentModel and add de next lines:

```
protected $table = 't_clients';
protected $primaryKey = 'pk_client';
```

So the result should be:

```
class Client extends Authenticatable implements CanResetPassword
{
    protected $table = 't_clients';
    protected $primaryKey = 'pk_client';
    use Notifiable;
}
```